# mysql conditional select based on a sale price

Tags: mysql, database, select, conditional-statements

I have a database of products. One of the attributes is a normal price (price), a sale price (sale_price), a sale expiration date (sale_expires) and a sale price that never expires flag (sale_never_expires).

I can write a nice query that gets me the basic information on the product and the current price:

SELECT stock,name,
(CASE WHEN (sale_never_expires='Y' AND sale_price > 0.0) 
        OR (sale_expires >= REPLACE(CURDATE(),'-','') AND sale_price > 0.0) THEN sale_price ELSE price END) as current_price FROM inventory WHERE delete_flag=0;

But that's not what I need. What I need is to be able to write a query that returns all products in inventory with a current price less than a given amount, say $100 for the sake of example. I just need the matching records and will worry about formatting later.

I've tried and tried to find a way to write this but I'm stuck. What can I do??

Comment: sale_expires is a string?

Comment: Yes, sale_expires is char(8). Example: 20130717

Answer (score 0):

Select * from tableName where current price <100

Should work fine unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: You might have misunderstood the problem. I suppose what I'm looking for a is a virtual field - current_price - that I can use for comparisons in a SELECT statement. How does one create one of those?

Answer (score 0):

a view might help.. it will just hide the complexity..

```
create view current_products as SELECT stock,name, (CASE ...
```

Comment: Would that let me write a query like this: SELECT stock,name,current_price FROM current_products WHERE current_price < 100.0 ?

Comment: I've figured this out on my own. What I needed was the HAVING clause. Here's what the proper query looks like:

SELECT stock,name, (CASE WHEN (sale_never_expires='Y' AND sale_price > 0.0) OR (sale_expires >= REPLACE(CURDATE(),'-','') AND sale_price > 0.0) THEN sale_price ELSE price END) as current_price FROM inventory WHERE delete_flag=0 HAVING current_price < 100.0;

That gets me the rows that I needed. Thanks for reading!